# Install Older Version of Laravel using Composer

Tags: laravel-4

How do I install older version of Laravel framework using composer? The current version is 4.1 and I want to install Laravel 4.0.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally it works, I just did four things:

> composer create-project laravel/laravel mobilebanking 4.0

Change "dev" to "stable" in composer.json

Then run

> composer self-update

After that, run this command

> composer update --no-scripts

Answer (score 80):

either update your `composer.json` to what GregD mentioned or fetch it directly with

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.0.*
```

prefer this, as there can be some caveats when getting version 4.1 and wanting to downgrade (or even upgrade).

Comment: This is a very good option but am getting the Runtime error saying: Class Monolog\\Logger not found

Comment: The error may be because the shell is confused by the wildcard. Try installing a specific version without the asterisk at the end.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
composer create–project laravel/laravel MiProyecto 5.3.*  o  
composer create–project laravel/laravel=5.3.* MiProyecto
```

Answer (score 2):

Browse packagist - https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel
Find version you need and add it to composer i.e.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/laravel": "v4.0.0",
},
```

Comment: "4.0.*" would be the best option here, so you'd still be on the 4.0 branch, but get all the fixes for it.

Comment: Thanks GregD, problem with this option is that I will have to manually downgrate to version 4.0.*

Answer (score 0):

Install it like this:

```sh
composer create-project laravel/laravel path/to/your/directory version
```

For Laravel versions 5.5 it looks like this:

```sh
composer create-project laravel/laravel path/to/your/directory 5.5
```