# How to install Laravel 3?

Tags: laravel, hyperlink

I tried to learn laravel 5 and 4. Both seems hard for me, so I thought of starting from laravel 3. I searched everywhere but I couldn't find anywhere. Please tell me where can I download laravel 3. 
I tried this https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/3.0 but it prompts an error, please help me.

Comment: Using an older version of Laravel won't make it any easier. There is also a lot of resource available around the place when it comes to learning either 4 or 5 too.

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: I am really not sure, what are you trying to achieve ? Although L3 was good in the past, L5 is more light and more user friendly. I'd suggest learning more about updated version.

Comment: Not a good idea to start from L3. If you find L5 too difficult i suggest to learn more of "pure" PHP: object oriented programming, basic design patterns, ecc. After that come back to Laravel....

Comment: Thank you , I'll learn pure PHP before I start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You cannot currently use Laravel 3 anymore.

---

Laravel 3 does not support PHP 5.5.

The introduction of generators [broke some of its code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3.0/laravel/helpers.php#L563), since `yield` is now a reserved word.

Interestingly enough, it's quite possible that it *will* work in PHP 7, since PHP 7 allows using reserved words in function/method names.

Answer (score 0):

You can install older version of laravel like that, follow the link i hope it will help you. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043391/install-older-version-of-laravel-using-composer)

Comment: That link is only for composer-enabled version of Laravel. Version 3 did not use composer.

Comment: @TariqHusain You can see on packagist that there is no L3. https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel