# Laravel - Reportico not working

Tags: php, laravel, report, open-source

I am using [Reportico](http://www.reportico.org/laravel/public/index.php/installation) reporting module, and follow the installation instructions listed on official website, but somehow its not working.

Here are the steps I followed:

I have created a fresh laravel project mentioned on [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4):

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Then within the project root directory, I executed the following command by using composer:

```
composer require reportico/laravel-reportico "~5.2"
```

And remaining steps are same as listed on Reportico website. It did not give me any error message in the steps, but finally when I go to the url:

```
http://localhost:8000/index.php/reportico
```

It is showing error message that route not found.

Can anybody suggest how to fix this, or is there any free-open-source reporting tool which I can use with Laravel project.

Comment: I think you need to install `Laravel` `5.2` or `5.3` since they don't have support for the new version of `Laravel`.

Comment: Yes this may be the case. Thanks for your thoughts. Since we have moved far away with 5.4, at the moment we could not go back. May be we have to look for some other alternative tool.

Comment: if you want you can install laravel 5.2 or any older version check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043391/install-older-version-of-laravel-using-composer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project was upgraded to 5.4 in February, but unfortunately there was a problem which made it unavailable to the world. I believe I have fixed this now so please retry the composer require command and you should get version 5.4 of the package.

If it doesnt work you could try using the following instead to force the version update:

```
composer require "reportico/laravel-reportico" "dev-master"
```

Also, the error messsage you are getting implies you havent added to your config/app.php file in the providers section

```
Reportico\Reportico\ReporticoServiceProvider::class
```

This is very important. Please let me know if this works.

Peter

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked with Laravel 5.4. Now showing Reportico Administration Page.

Comment: there is one problem if you can help, when I created fresh laravel 5.4 project, and then your mentioned command, then it is working fine. But when I use this composer command in my real Laravel 5.4 project, it is showing same error message: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: ... In this project I have also used another plugin https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator, is it conflicting with this?

Comment: Hi there, before i investigate, are you sure you added the line "Reportico\Reportico\ReporticoServiceProvider::class" in the config/app.php file, since that error is caused by that line missing?

Comment: Ok... are you able to put an echo statement in the ReporticoServiceProvider file under vendor/reportico/laravel-reportico/src/ReporticoReportico and rcheck thethen check that it is displayed to show it is being included, or introduce a syntax error in that file to check if it is being included? Hope that makes sense... happy to look at the site if you want to give me access and are able?

Comment: Actually its not the plug-in problem. I created a fresh laravel project, installed this plugin. and then repotico. its working fine. But somehow still I could not understand why my real project is not working. One difference I found in publish command. these lines are missing in output when I publish in real project. 

Copied File [\vendor\reportico\laravel-reportico\src\config\config.php] To [\config\reportico.php]
Copied Directory [\vendor\reportico\laravel-reportico\src\Reportico\Reportico\assets] To [\public\vendor\reportico]

Remaining lines are same in output.

Comment: I put an ECHO as first line in boot() function in ReporticoServiceProvider file, but nothing happens.

Comment: I was get busy with another project. Now I switched back to this project and followed these steps. Its working now. Thanks for your help! @PeterDeed

Comment: i followed everything and it still doesnt work on laravel 5.4 :( @PeterDeed any help?

Comment: i just figured it out,. before doing php artisan vendor:publish make sure you do  php artisan config:cache  first

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Changing the url to below worked for me

```
http://localhost:8000/index.php/reportico
```

Hope it helps someone.